# Mock an injection in an enum

Tags: java, dependency-injection, enums, guice

For a framework I am trying to inject another class in my enum to provide some environment information. It appears to work however I do not know how to test this in a unit test. Please help..

Enum:

```
public enum BestemmingBad implements Bestemming {

 TEST("test"),
 TEST2("test2");

 BestemmingBad(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        final String jmsServer = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(MyEnvironmentConfig.class).retrieveJmsServerName();
        return jmsServer + "/" + value;
    }
}
```

My test;

```
public class BestemmingenTest extends ExtendedEasyMockSupport {

private Environment environmentMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    environmentMock = createMock(Environment.class);
}

@Test
public void BestemmingBadTb5Test() throws UnknownHostException {
     expect(environmentMock.getComputerName()).andReturn("TB5");
     replayAll();

     final BestemmingBad bestemming = BestemmingBad.TEST;
     assertThat(bestemming.getUrl(), is("jms@testserver@jms1/test"));
}

private class TestModule extends TestGuiceModule {

    @Provides
    public Environment provideEnvironment() {
        return environmentMock;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your enum already implements an interface which should make providing a mock implementation trivial.

Comment: What are you trying to mock here? Is it `retrieveJmsServerName` method?

Comment: I am trying to mock the computer this runs from (I have multiple with unfortunately different settings) and I want to check if this system keep working in a unit test. The environment.class is injected into the MyEnvironmentConfig.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You shouldn't "inject" into an `enum`

Instead use a good old `switch` statement, or move your injection point into something really injectable like a class.

Why are you injecting an `enum`? It makes no sense. An enum is entirely static. You shouldn't add behavior to an enum unless is extremely basic and consistent. What you're doing here is neither. Also, calling your method will be very slow because Guice will have to initialize the `Injector` at every single call, which is definitely not what you want.

What you should do instead is moving the business logic outside of the enum itself:

```
public enum BestemmingBad implements Bestemming {
  TEST("test"), TEST2("test2");
  private final String value;
  BestemmingBad(String value) { this.value = value; }
  public String getValue() { return value; }
}

public class UrlGetter {
  private String jmsServer;
  @Inject UrlGetter(MyEnvironmentConfig config) {
    jmsServer = config.retrieveJsmServerName();
  }
  public String getUrl(Bestemming bestemming) { // or BestemmingBad
    return jmsServer + "/" + bestemming.getValue();
  }
}
```

Then your test doesn't require anything complicated: just test `UrlGetter.getUrl(Bestemming)` very basically.